# Conditional compilation for with and without concepts?

Tags: c++, backwards-compatibility, c++17, c++-concepts

I am playing with `g++` concepts. Sometimes I want to compile with `clang` which doesn't have concepts yet.

How can I compile `concepts` code with a compiler with out concepts?

I am doing this trick now to `#define` the concept itself simply as the `class` (or `typename`) keyword. (I am doing this based on Stepanov's books).

```
#if __cpp_concepts >= 201507
template <class T>
concept bool Integral = is_quantity<T>::value; //Full concepts syntax
#else
#define Integral typename //Stepanov trick
#endif

template<Integral I> I f(I i){return i + 1;}

int main(){f(2);}
```

It seems I can leave the declarations untouched (and without the concept constrain, but the code compiles).

Is this the recommended way to deal with this issue. 
Any problems that could appear down the road.

One problem I have now is that I can't put the concept definition inside a namespace.
Another problem I see is that SFINAE case can break when compiling without concepts.

Are there better workarounds?

---

This illustrates the problem with the case of namespaces:

```
#if __cpp_concepts >= 201507
namespace demo{
template <class T>
concept bool Integral = is_quantity<T>::value;
}
#else
#define demoIntegral typename
#endif
```

This forces me to put a conditional in all template declarations.

```
template<
#if __cpp_concepts >= 201507
demo::Integral
#else
demoIntegral
#endif
I> I f(I i){return i + 1;}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what that solution will accomplish. Most uses of concepts involve multiple function overloads. Many uses of concepts involve an explicit `requires` clause. Neither of these can be handled with your system for turning off concepts. So it's not clear what you intend to do in the common case.

Comment: @NicolBolas, thank you for the context. Yes, I started using concepts, and it looks like it quickly becomes impossible to keep (compiler) backwards compatibility. I guess people can summarize partial workarounds here.